# Get details from Android Device Policy after enrolment via Android Management API using flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-management-api, android-device-manager

I enroll a fully-managed device with Android Management API using qrCode.

After enrollment, **I want to get any kind of detail of enrolmentToken or qrCode that was used to enroll the device**, so I can ping my server of the details and update the database accordingly.

I want to implement this in flutter framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing can be done by implementing pub/sub in which I can subscribe every enterprise to a certain topic and allow ENROLLMENT notification which listens for such notifications.

Answer (score 0):

To identify which enrollment token an admin used during device provisioning, you can use the [devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) method. When using this method, the following fields will provide relevant information about the token:

- The [enrollmentTokenName](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#Device.FIELDS.enrollment_token_name:%7E:text=contains%20that%20data.-,enrollmentTokenName,-string) field contains the token's name.
- The [enrollmentTokenData](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#Device.FIELDS.enrollment_token_name:%7E:text=on%20the%20device.-,enrollmentTokenData,-string) field - if an enrollment token provides additional data, this field contains that data.

Additionally, you can also use [enrollmentTokens.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens/get) to get more information about the enrollment used. This method gets an *active, unexpired enrollment token*, and only a partial view of EnrollmentToken is returned (all the fields but `name` and `expirationTimestamp` are empty).